# System.IO.Directory.GetFiles doesn't find any files

Tags: vb.net

I am having an issue where I have 2 GetFiles that don't seem to be able to find any files. I have commented the 2 problem lines. I have 1 file in the sourcedir and 1 in a subfolder of the sourcedir. If I take off FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, then it will find the file in the sourcedir, but not in subfolders. With FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, it finds no files at all. I am running VS2013 as Admin.

```
'For some reason, this finds no files--> '

Dim xFilesCount = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcedir, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories).Length
Dim xFilesTransferred As Integer = 0

'For some reason, this finds no files'

For Each xFiles In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcedir, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories)
     System.IO.File.Move(xFiles, xNewLocation & "\" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(xFiles))
     xFilesTransferred += 1
```

Edit:

Thank you very much! I ended up using the following code, in case someone else runs across this same issue.

```
Dim xFilesCount = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcedir, "*.pf_import", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length
            Dim xFilesTransferred As Integer = 0

            For Each xFiles In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcedir, "*.pf_import", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

                System.IO.File.Move(xFiles, xNewLocation & "\" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(xFiles))
                xFilesTransferred += 1

                ProgressBar1.Value = xFilesTransferred * 100 / xFilesCount
                ProgressBar1.Update()
                Application.DoEvents()
            Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcedir, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

#### Problem #1

Currently you are missing one argument.

Because [GetFiles() signature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles(v=vs.110).aspx) is:

```
GetFiles(String, String, SearchOption)
```

**Important:**

Please place `Option Strict On` as the first line of your code module. This will help you to avoid these errors. Ideally, set `Option Strict On` in project options so it will be applied to all files. Never work on larget projects without `Option Explicit On` and `Option Strict On`. (I also recommend `Option Infer Off`.)

#### Problem #2

Correct constant to use with GetFiles() is

```vb
System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories
```

and not

```vb
FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Why `Option Infer Off`?

Comment: I made that change on both GetFiles lines, not I get the following error on the first GetFiles. 

Enum value was out of legal range.

Comment: @Enigmativity – reason targetted for this Q&A: because vb.net beginners get better sense what they are doing. :) Can be relaxed back to On later, but this can be a bit contraproductive – I mean, in large projects, where no one remembers the source, it can be for everyone's good to have type information obvious.

Comment: @miroxlav Yes Yes Yes Dear your'e grate thanks allot

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify where: sourcedir is - but if it is a root directory you will crash into the special folders pretty quickly (my documents, my music, etc.) with SearchOption.AllDirectories.

If that is the case you should be seeing an "unauthorizedAccessException" (largely because those directories don't actually exist) which you will need to catch in order to proceed with the other "non-special" folders.  Then, you can re-visit those folders (MyDocuments for example) like:

```
Dim myPath As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments.ToString
```

(That will return something like: c:\users\cptnvic\documents)

Then, something like:

```
For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(myPath, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.*")
```

will return a list of folders to recurse.  You only need to append those folders to myPath.  This method does not require any administrative changes (for the current user).

Good luck!